# Using the letter L in long variable declaration

Tags: java, long-integer, variable-declaration

```
long l2 = 32;
```

When I use the above statement, I don't get an error (I did not used `l` at the end), but when I use the below statement, I get this error:

> The literal 3244444444 of type int is out of range

```
long l2 = 3244444444;
```

If I use `long l2 = 3244444444l;`, then there's no error.

What is the reason for this? Using l is not mandatory for long variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`3244444444` is interpreted as a literal integer but can't fit in a 32-bit `int` variable. It needs to be a **literal long value**, so it needs an `l` or `L` at the end:

```
long l2 = 3244444444l; // or 3244444444L
```

More info:

- [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), specifically **Default Values** and **Literals** sections.

Comment: But i declared as long.How it interpreted as integer

Comment: @PSR the variable is integer, the literal value is interpreted as `int` and when being assigned to the `long` variable it will become a `long` value. Refer to the link in my answer for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Note that while int literals will be auto-widened to long when assigning to a long variable, you will need to use an explicit long literal when expressing a value that is

1. greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647)`

   (or)
2. less than `Integer.MIN_VALUE (-2147483648)`:

   ```
   long x1 = 12; //OK
   long x2 = 2147483648; // not OK! That's not a valid int literal
   long x3 = 2147483648L; // OK
   ```