# Java long without suffix

Tags: java, primitive-types

I've read that to declare a long, you need to suffix the number with `l` or `L`

So far, so good. But what happens, if I omit this suffix?

```
long l1 = 100l; // ok
long l2 = 100L; // ok

long l3 = 100; // ?
```

Is `l3` now an integer or still a long?

Comment: `long l3 = 100;`<- `100` is an integer, `l3` is a long. You can assign an integer to a long an java will do the conversation for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738232/using-the-letter-l-in-long-variable-declaration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`long l3 = 100` declares a long, assigns an `int` to it (`100` is an int literal), which results in the int being promoted to long implicitly.

The `int` range, however, has limits. There are valid `long` values that can't be declared without the `L` suffix:

```
long l3 = 2147483648; //doesn't compile
```

`2147483647` is the max value for int and anything above it can't be used without the `l` suffix *as a long literal*. In fact, using just `2147483648` anywhere in Java source code won't compile because without any suffix, the literal is expected to be a valid int, and that number is too big for an int.

Comment: Mandatory JLS reference: integer literals ([JLS § 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)); primitive types in assigmnent contexts are subject to widening ([JLS § 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html)).